# How can I invoke external command to transform json using jq?

Tags: jq

I have the following json input:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.example.com", 
  "html": "<html>...</html>"
}
```

How can I use `jq` to extract all JavaScript `<script>` tags from `html` using `pup`?

For an example, I can extract all `script`s I want from a single html using a pipe call:

```
cat example.json | jq -r .html | pup 'script[type="text/javascript"] text{}'
```

I would like to put all of these extracted scripts in a new resulting json:

```
{
  "url": "https://www.example.com",
  "scripts": [
    "<script>...",
    "<script>..."
  ]
}
```

If I try using:

```
jq -c '{url: .url, scripts: [.html | pup "script[type=text/javascript] text{}"]}'
```

it will not work because `pup` is an external command and not part of `jq`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the output format of `pup`?

Comment: When using the `json{}` output, it looks like: `{"tag":"script","text":"content","type":"text/javascript"}`. `text{}` however returns only `content`.

Comment: And `content` contains one script tag per line or does a script tag span multiple lines?

Comment: It is a single line output.

Comment: Use `jq` to get the HTML; use an HTML parser to extract the `<script>` elements from `jq`'s *output* (just like you already have).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible directly from jq (jq cannot call external programs from within a jq program). But if your input only contains a single object with those two properties, the following should work in POSIX shells:

```
{
  jq '{url}' input.json;
  jq -r '.html' input.json | pup ... | jq -Rs '{scripts: .}';
} | jq -s 'add'
```

It's also possible to invoke `jq` with `--arg` – which still invokes jq 2 times and reads your input twice:

```
jq --arg scripts "$(jq -r '.html' input.json | pup ... )" \
'{url, $scripts}' input.json
```

Sample output:

```json
{
  "url": "http://example.com",
  "scripts": "...."
}
```

Comment: This will convert the JS snippets linewise into array items. I think, OP wants the items to be whole scripts (i.e. a tagwise conversion)...

Comment: @pmf that was an assumption, because the expected output in the question contained one script element per line. The comment about the output format of `pup` is still unanswered.

Comment: I have tried using this as: `jq --argjson scripts "$(jq -r '.html' input.json | pup "script[type="text/javascript"] json{}" )" '{url, scripts: ($scripts/"\n")}' input.json` but I am getting: `jq: error (at input.json:1): array ([{"tag":"sc...) and string ("\n") cannot be divided` Just a note, I am trying to do this with multiple object (one per line), but even a single object per file would be enough to get me started

Comment: `$scripts/"\n"` splits a string on newlines. If you want to have the full output as value, simply use `$scripts` without further transformations: `{url, $scripts}`

Comment: This is almost it, but I can figure out on my own how to remap the json output of scripts to only include `text` field. I guess there is no other way to support multiple jsons in a single file since this reads the input twice?

Comment: @alturkovic If you need text, why generate JSON output? If you need text, generate text output and pass it to jq as `--arg`

Comment: I have not used `jq` very much, so I didn't know about all these options, this is all still very new to me :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Use `json{}` instead of `text{}` to enable post-processing with jq. For example:

```bash
jsonfile='example.json'
jq '.scripts = (input | map(.text // empty))' "$jsonfile" <(
  jq -r '.html' "$jsonfile" | pup 'script[type=text/javascript] json{}'
)
```

Comment: I am getting `Cannot index string with string "text"` using this example

Comment: @alturkovic This answer assumes, the content of file `example.json` is JSON in the form `{"url": "…", "html": "…"}` (your sample input), so `jq -r '.html' example.json` can extract the content of the `.html` field. If it is fed with a (JSON encoded) string instead, you get the error message shown.

Comment: Oops, my bad, I tried running it on a file with multiple jsons. Works for a single object by appending the `scripts` field to existing JSON in the file.

Comment: In a "multiple JSON" scenario, pup would receive a stream of HTMLs, and presumably clutter up all the JS scripts in its output, so it'd be hard to reassign them to their corresponding HTML sources.